# append "_X" to a input value and raise it

Tags: jquery

I need to check if a value of an input field is really unique. Therefore the input value will be checked via AJAX. If result = 1 -> everything is fine (=unique value).
If result = 0, it means that there is already the same value in the DB, so the input value has to be modified to "value_X". X is a number, which should be raised. So I need to check if the modified value is also unique. If this isn't the case x will be raised until it is a unique value (result = 1).

```
var slug = $('#slug').val();
check_slug(slug);

function check_slug(slug) { 
    $.ajax({
        url: "script.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: { 'slug': slug },
        dataType: "json"
    })
    .done(function( json ) {
        if (json.result==1) {
            // slug is ok
        }
        else {
            // add "_X" and check
        }
    })
    .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
        var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
        console.warn( "Request Failed: " + err );
    });
}
```

Comment: You want to make a recursive AJAX call - I don't think that is the best approach. Let the server determine the proper value and return that.

Comment: You are completely right. I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend doing this work server side instead. Have your API figure out what the slug value should be, and return it! Then the AJAX call just happens once, and you know what the slug ended up being.

However, if you insist on sending request after request until you eventually find the right slug, then this should do the trick:

```
var slug = $('#slug').val();
check_slug(0, slug);

function check_slug(count, slug) {
    var numberedSlug = slug;
    if(count > 0) {
        numberedSlug = slug + "_" + count;
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "script.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: { 'slug': numberedSlug },
        dataType: "json"
    })
    .done(function( json ) {
        if (json.result == 1) {
            // slug is ok
            // do what you do with ok slugs
        } else {
            check_slug(count + 1, slug);
        }
    })
    .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
        var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
        console.warn( "Request Failed: " + err );
    });
}
```

EDIT: It should be noted that 'numberedSlug' is the valid slug upon success.